# Getting primacy as columns primary, secondary,tertiary to eliminate duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to get the different functions, scopes and primacy for an employee, (primacy can go up to 5 functions) :

```
    with employeeScopeFunctions as 
(
    SELECT
        e.employeeId, 
        es.FunctionId,
        ef.Label,
        c.CompanyName,
        es.SortOrder
    FROM
        employee e 
        LEFT JOIN employee_scope es on es.employeeId = e.employeeId
        LEFT JOIN employee_function ef on es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId
        LEFT JOIN Company c ON es.CompanyId = c.ID
    WHERE 
        e.EmployeeId = 54
),
RankingBySum AS
(
    SELECT 
        esf.EmployeeId, 
        esf.Label,
        STUFF (
            (
                SELECT ',' + CompanyName 
                FROM employeeScopeFunctions es
                WHERE esf.EmployeeId=es.EmployeeId AND esf.FunctionId=es.FunctionId
                FOR XML PATH('')
            )
            , 1,1,'') AS Companies,
        SUM(esf.SortOrder) as sumOrder,

        SumRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY esf.EmployeeId ORDER BY SUM(esf.SortOrder) ASC)
    FROM 
        employeeScopeFunctions esf
    GROUP BY 
        esf.EmployeeId,
        esf.FunctionId,
        esf.Label

)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
    R.EmployeeId,

    R.Label,



    primacy = CASE R.SumRanking
        WHEN 1 THEN 'primary'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'secondary'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'tertiary' END
FROM
    RankingBySum AS R) t

    PIVOT (
    MAX(t.Label)
    FOR t.primacy IN  ([primary],[secondary],[tertiary])

    ) AS PVT
```

The output I already have to get the primacy of an employee :

```
    EmployeeId primary                         secondary                               tertiary
  54        Group  Chief Executive Officer  Group Regional Chief Executive Officer  Director
```

My expected output to avoid duplication is to gather all the information in one record like below :

```
EmployeeId PrimaryFunction       SecondaryFunction TertiaryFunction                   PrimaryCompanies SecondaryCompanies TertiaryCompanies

54         Group Chief Executive Officer Group     Chief Executive Officer Director   C1,C2,X5          X6,F6              VY,G7
```

Comment: this operation is called PIVOT, search around a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select PrimaryFunction, SecondaryFunction etc as columns. You can do this by adding further joins - something like this:

```
SELECT
    o.employeeId, 
    es1.Label as PrimaryFunction,
    es2.Label as SecondaryFunction,
    es3.Label as TertiaryFunction,
    o.Companies...
FROM
    [other tables] o
    LEFT JOIN employeeScopeFunctions es1 on es1.employeeId = e.employeeId and es1.SortOrder=1
    LEFT JOIN  employeeScopeFunctions es2 on es2.employeeId = e.employeeId and es1.SortOrder=2 ...
WHERE 
    ...
```

You will need to rearrange your CTE a bit, but that's the general idea.